# Disable a textfield

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a textfield, and need to disable it.

My code;

```
self.personTextField.userInteraction=NO;
```

But, when i click on the above textfield, the Keyboard pops out. (Yet i am unable to type). What i want to do is, completely disable the textfield even without popping out a keyboard upon click.

note: I only need to completely disable the above textfield (`personTextField`), There might be other textfields but i need to only disable the `personTextField`

Answer (score 3):

self.personTextField.enabled = NO;

Comment: But, still the keyboard pops up when i add `enable=NO`. Is there a fix for this ?

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. When I add just a UITextField to an empty nib and uncheck enabled, no keyboard appears when I tap it. Check your code to make sure you aren't accidentally enabling it somewhere.